# Vertica : Function return multiple column

Tags: sql, function, reusability, vertica

I have around 40 queries which run on various tables and at the end of each query is a sub query for calculation of some metrics based on the values from above sub-queries. The final sub-query in each query looks like this -

```
SELECT dimension,
       CASE when(impressions!=0) THEN clicks/impressions*100
           ELSE NULL
       END ctr,
       CASE when(impressions!=0) THEN gross_rev/impressions*1000
           ELSE NULL
       END cpm,
       CASE when(clicks!=0) THEN gross_rev/clicks
           ELSE NULL
       END cpc,
       CASE when(actions!=0) THEN gross_rev/actions
           ELSE NULL
       END AS cpa,
       CASE when(post_click!=0) THEN gross_rev/post_click
           ELSE NULL
       END AS pc_cpa
```

I want to reuse these formulas so wanted to write a function. But a vertica function does not return more than one columns.

Any idea on how to re-use these sub queries in a function or any other reusability technique for vertica.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by creating your own Vertica UDX  , the UDX should be of TRANSFORM type , using this type of UDX  the output schema is unrelated to the input schema , so basically you can provide list of columns as an input   and the output can be different list with different size .

You can see some examples in GitHub https://github.com/vertica/Vertica-Extension-Packages

I hope you will find it useful

Thanks